# How to determine the UTM zone in a world file

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, utm, world-file

According to this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) the UTM zone is ambiguous. If so, how come when I load it in some GIS software it seems to know where the image is located on Earth? How do I determine the UTM zone in a world file? I want to create a world file for my image and I have the gps coordinates of the corners of my image file. But I am not sure how to convert that to UTM values pertaining to the world file format.

To give a bit more context I am trying to create this world file so that I can georeference images on JOSM and annotate on top of it.

Comment: UTM is not at all relevant if you have GPS coordinates which are in degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this is that the world file parameters can be any UTM zone you want. When you load it into your GIS software, for example, in the case of JOSM, you must first specify the map projection you are using, ie. UTM. zone number and letter. Then the software will just assume the parameters in the world file are defined in the map projection you specified.